# Can the output differ when code is written in different ways?

Tags: python, markov-chains

This is the code that I have written for the following question:

1. Take an example of a continuous time markov chain. The arrival rate at a counter is 3 people/min and the departure rate is 5 people/min. There can be a maximum of 10 people in the line. We have to convert this into a discrete time markov chain using the uniformization technique. This techique involves finding a parameter $\delta$ . $\delta$ << 1/($\lambda$ + $\mu$) where $\lambda$ is the arrival rate and $\mu$ is the departure rate. We multiply $\lambda$ and $\mu$ with $\delta$ which determine the outgoing and incoming probabilities. With the remaining probability the Markov chain stays in the same state. Using KL Divergence, find n for which the divergence between the first two rows of the matrix $P^n$ is very small. Plot $\delta$ vs n plot for different values of n. (where P is the transition matrix).

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# function for calcuating the KL Divergence of a matrix P
def kl_div(P):
    D=0
    for i in range(0,11):
        if P[0][i] != 0:
            D += (P[0][i]*np.log(P[0][i]/P[1][i]))
        else:
            pass
    return D

l = 3 # arrival rate
u = 5 # departure rate

d = [1/((10**y)*(l+u)) for y in range(1,11)]
n = []

for x in d:

    lx = l*x
    ux = u*x
    
    P = np.zeros((11,11))

    P[0][0] = 1-ux
    for i in range(1,11):
        P[i][i-1] = ux
    for i in range(1,10):
        P[i][i] = 1-lx-ux
    for i in range (10):
        P[i][i+1] = lx
    P[10][10] = 1-ux

    d1 = kl_div(P) #finding the value of KL divergence of P

    temp = 1 #increasing the value of temp for the first iteration

    # finding the values of KL divergence until the matrix converges
    while True:
        P = P @ P
        temp += 1
        res = kl_div(P)
        if res<0.000000001: #threshold for convergence
            n.append(temp)
            break

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, figsize = [8,6])

ax.plot(d, n, linewidth = 3 , color = 'green')
ax.set_ylabel('Number of iterations for convergence', fontsize = 13)
ax.set_xlabel('Value of delta', fontsize = 13)
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.grid(linestyle = '--', alpha = 1)

plt.show()
```

The given plot for me shows that with the decrease in value of $\delta$, n increases. But it shows a very small number (here, in 50s). The answer is expercted to be in 500s. Is there something wrong here?